# macOS: Karma reconnecting in X seconds... ng test stops watching for changes

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

In my Angular app using Angular CLI, I can successfully run the tests using `ng test`:

[image]

however after some time the browser looses the connectivity and the console stops reacting on code changes:

[image]

then I have to kill the `ng test` process manually otherwise it just hangs and consumes a lot of CPU.

I've tried playing with the `karma.conf.js` by playing with those parameters (which weren't originally there):

```
captureTimeout
browserNoActivityTimeout
browserDisconnectTimeout
browserDisconnectTolerance
```

but apparently those has not effect at all.

My karma.conf.js file: https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3/blob/master/src/karma.conf.js

Note: when running the same project using Ubuntu the problem is NOT there.

Comment: I checked it on Mac and it is working fine

Comment: @ArunRedhu what have you checked exactly ? a new Angular app or my app ?

Comment: I cloned your app and run `ng test`. Then change the test cases several times and it is working fine.

Comment: @ArunRedhu thanks for checking, then it's definitely something wrong with my system. What can it be?